# How is pointer ++*ptr++ evaluated

Tags: c, pointers, operator-precedence, unary-operator, postfix-operator

So I'm quite confused as to how the post-increment is not evaluated first.  (According to precedence post-increment comes first.) Can someone please explain this?

Consider the code given below:

```
int main()
{
    char arr[] = "iitbforgoodlife";
    char *ptr = arr;
    
    while(*ptr != '\0')
        ++*ptr++;
    
    printf("%s %s", arr, ptr);
    
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is: `jjucgpshppemjgf`

Comment: It's evaluated as a coding bug — the author should be deprived of teaching and coding privileges.

Comment: What do *you* think should happen and why?

Comment: @G.M. I thought something like ++*(ptr++) => ++(*increment pointer) =>  increment the value at pointer something like this

Comment: The statement `++*ptr++;` is essentially the same as `char *temp = ptr; ptr = ptr + 1; *temp = *temp + 1;`

Comment: Apparently, I need some remedial C — why is this undefined behaviour?  It's appalling code, but I don't see the source of UB.

Comment: It may not be a bug in the sense of having UB, but it exhibits poor enough programmer judgement that I think "coding bug" is not an altogether unreasonable assessment.

Answer (score 4):

Operator precedence is only about what operators bind to their operands first, not about the order in which the operations are carried out or when the variables are actually modified.

When you write

```
++*ptr++;
```

it is indeed equivalent to

```
++*(ptr++);
```

However this does not mean that `ptr` has to be incremented before the rest of the expression is evaluated. In fact, `*(ptr++)` **must** derrefence the **current** value of the pointer. Because the semantic of the post-increment operator is that `ptr++` yields the value of `ptr` and increments `ptr` (it doesn't specify *when* the increment happens).

In other words, the compiler may chose to increment `*ptr` and then the pointer or it may first increment the pointer and then use its previous value to increment the pointed object.

The best thing is not to rely on that knowledge. Always prefer to write simpler code:

```
while(*ptr != 0) {
    ++*ptr;
    ptr++;
}
```

My personal rule of thumb is that you should avoid using `++` with any other operator as much as possible. In particular, if you have two instances of `++` in an expression, it is very likely wrong or poorly written.

Comment: The two "either" cases are exactly equivalent anyway (because of the as-if rule) .   Assuming `ptr` has no side-effect.

Comment: Re “it doesn't specify *when* the increment happens”: This is partially specified: C 2018 6.5.2.4 2 says “The value computation of the result is sequenced before the side effect of updating the stored value of the operand.” So the update of `ptr` must happen after its value is read to determine the result. This imposes very little constraint on the compiler due to rules about observable behavior, but the fact the read and the write are sequenced means they do not violate the 6.5 2 rule about unsequenced side effects (yet the write remains unsequenced relative to other parts of an expression).

Comment: @M.M I decided to remove the two pieces of code. It wasn't necessary. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Re "*In other words, the compiler may chose to increment *ptr and then the pointer or it may first increment the pointer and then use its previous value to increment the pointed object.*", yeah, but that's transparent. The outcome is the same in both cases. So this is a very misleading statement.

Comment: Why misleading? I'm letting OP understand that it's the compiler, not how the programmer parenthesizes their expressions, that determines when the increment will actually take place. Also that post-increment does not necessarily mean that the increment is performed after the expression has been evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ++*ptr++;
//  | |   |
//  | |   ` post-increment
//  | ` dereference
//  ` pre-increment
```

The post-increment, being a primary expression operator, has highest precedence. The result of the operator is the original value (the increment may happen any time before the end of the sequence point).

Next is the unary operator `*` which dereferences the pointer to return the underlying object, which is a character from the array `arr`.

Finally, the pre-increment operator, also a unary operator, which has the same precedence as `*`. However, it is applied later because operators of the same precedence are associated in some precedence specific order. For unary operators, they are associated right-to-left. Therefore, the pre-increment is applied to the object resulting from the `*` operator.

So, if you wanted expanded pseudo code to explain it:

```
optr = ptr;
val = *optr;
nval = val + 1;
*optr = nval;
ptr = ptr + 1;
```

Where the last assignment could happen at any point after the first assignment.

Comment: The post-increment may occur at any point between the operation and the next sequence point. Not after.

Comment: @WeatherVane You are right, I was imprecise.

Comment: It may happen *before* the sequence point. It may take effect immediately after the operation, but it *must* happen before the sequence point.

Comment: There is no "right to left evaluation" in C.  There is right to left precedence, but precedence is different to evaluation order.  Nothing in this code involves right-to-left precedence anyway . This answer needs a major rewrite really

Comment: `*` and pre `++` have the same precedence @M.M

Comment: @WeatherVane Again, you are right, I should not say value of the variable, but value of the result of the operator. Thanks!

Comment: @jxh there is no other possible application of `++*x` than applying `++` to the result of `*x` (regardless of any precedence rule). Operators can't "jump over" other operators as such

Comment: But that's just the semantics of the syntax. It *could* have been defined in an outside -> inside order. @M.M

Comment: @jxh well it's the syntax, not the semantics ... there's no possible grammar rule that would make `++*x` parse as `*(++x)` , you would be abandoning the idea of language grammar entirely

Comment: I am not sure I follow. A grammar would allow a collection of unary operators to precede an expression. How that collection of unary operators affects the expression would be semantics of the syntax, wouldn't it? @M.M

Comment: Re “… operators of the same precedence are associated in some precedence specific order…”: Associativity is for where grammar otherwise admits multiple parsings. For example, in some grammar, `a+b+c`, the grammar could allow parsing as either `(a+b)+c` or `a+(b+c)`, and then an associativity rule would be needed to choose. However, this does not occur with `++*x`; this can only be parsed as `++(*x)`, and no associativity rule applies. Further, the C grammar is written such that the parsing is unambiguous, so the C standard does not specify associativity outside the grammar…

Comment: … When people say C operators have one associativity or another, this is only in the context of informal rules about precedence.

Comment: no... the grammar rules (which is syntax) turn the sequence of tokens into an expression tree, in an un-ambiguous way. A unary expression by definition is an operator with one operand ; the grammar rule consists of the operator token followed by the name of another grammar rule (possibly the same rule) , so the tokens following the operator have to match a grammar rule in of themself (not dependent on the operator)

Comment: @EricPostpischil I concede that the C grammar doesn't permit another interpretation of that sequence of tokens. But I don't think it is incorrect to explain the associativity convention for evaluating C expressions to someone that will probably be looking it up in a precedence table.

Comment: Grammars do permit ambiguity, with conventions to select a winning interpretation. E.g., which `if` an `else` should be associated with. I am just explaining hypothetically that another interpretation is possible with a different grammar, but I will concede your point with respect to these sequence of operations in the C grammar. Thanks! @M.M

Answer (score 0):

The horrible expression `++*ptr++;` will increment whatever `ptr` points to and leave `ptr` incremented as well. Consequently each array element will be incremented by one.

It's evaluated like:

```
++(*(ptr++));
```

Consider it like:

```
char* temp = ptr;
*temp = *temp + 1;
ptr = temp + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this expression:

```
++*ptr++
```

This expression uses one postfix operator (postfix increment) and two unary operators (unary indirection operator and unary increment operator).

Postfix operators have a higher precedence than unary operators.

Unary operators are evaluated from right to left.

So you have the following sequence of operations.

1. From the C Standard (6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators)

> 2 **The result of the postfix++ operator is the value of the
> operand.** As a side effect, the value of the operand object is
> incremented (that is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to
> it). See the discussions of additive operators and compound assignment
> for information on constraints, types, and conversions and the effects
> of operations on pointers. The value computation of the result is
> sequenced before the side effect of updating the stored value of the
> operand. With respect to an indeterminately-sequenced function call,
> the operation of postfix++ is a single evaluation. Postfix ++ on an
> object with atomic type is a read-modify-write operation with
> memory_order_seq_cst memory order semantics.

So the value of the sub-expression `ptr++` is the value of the pointer before its increment.

2. (the C Standard, 6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators)

> 4 The unary * operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a
> function, the result is a function designator; **if it points to an
> object, the result is an lvalue designating the object**. If the
> operand has type "pointer to type", the result has type "type". If an
> invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the
> unary * operator is undefined.

3. And at last the lvalue supplied by the indirection operator is incremented using the unary increment operator (the C Standard, 6.5.3.1 Prefix increment and decrement operators)

> 2 **The value of the operand of the prefix++ operator is incremented.
> The result is the new value of the operand after incrementation.** The
> expression++E is equivalent to (E+=1). See the discussions of additive
> operators and compound assignment for information on constraints,
> types, side effects, and conversions and the effects of operations on
> pointers.

So due to operation precedence this expression statement

```
++*ptr++;
```

may be equivalently rewritten using parentheses like

```
++( *( ptr++ ) );
```

For example when initially the pointer `ptr` points to the first character of the array `arr`

```
char arr[] = "iitbforgoodlife";
char *ptr = arr;
```

when in the first iteration of the while loop after this statement

```
++*ptr++;
```

the first character of the array will be increnented and becomes equal to `'j'` and the pointer `ptr` itself will point to the second character of the array.

Pay attention to that the array `arr` initialized by the string literal

```
char arr[] = "iitbforgoodlife";
```

includes the terminating zero character `'\0'` of the string literal and when the terminating zero character is encountered in the array the while loop stops its iteration:

```
while(*ptr != '\0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Monadic operators are always executed from right to left (first right operators, then left ones), and fron the inside to the outside.  So first an increment of the pointer is scheduled to be done at the end, but the actual value is used to dereference the pointer, and then the value of the pointed out item is incremented.  The final value is the result of the increment of the pointed value, and the pointer is itself incremented after the statement is executed.

The overal result is to increment each character in the string to the next character value, resulting in something like

```
"jjucgpshppemjgf"
```

but as `ptr` will end pointing to the final `'\0'` in the string, the result will be to print the string above (without the quotes) and a space, and nothing else (the pointer `ptr` is left pointing to the final null in the string). No line end is printed, so the prompt will appear to the right of the space.